# Is apache serving only one application or are the PHP sessions being shared?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, session

I am having trouble understanding what's happening in my scenario. Either apache is always serving the first virtual hosts files or the php sessions are being shared.

I'm attempting to create a DEV/QA environment on the same server and I'm using the Symfony2 framework (thankfully prod is on a standalone and is not affected by this). The reason I am not using the Symfony front controllers is because I'm using [php deployer](https://deployer.org/) to deploy my verticals. I've created 2 directories:

`/var/www/html/app1`
`/var/www/html/app2`

and 2 virtual hosts:

`app.domain:80 points to app1`
`app.domain:8080 points to app2`

and 2 databases:

`app_dev: blank`
`app_qa: copy of prod`

App1 is my DEV where I can break things and I have full debug information showing. App2 is my QA where I have users test things.

Here is the behavior I observe after I restart apache:

If I browse to DEV after the apache restart I see data/code from DEV and everything works fine. Now if I open QA (whether in the same browser or another different browser) I still see the same data from DEV. Now if I restart apache again and browse to QA first this time I see data/code from QA. If I then open DEV it's still QA.

Why is that happening and how can I prevent this. I don't know if it's my apache configuration or if it's because the php sessions are being shared between the two hosts.

Virtual Host configurations:

App1:80

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app1/current/web
ServerName app1.domain
<Directory "/var/www/html/app1/current/web">
AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

App2:8080

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app2/current/web
ServerName app2.domain
<Directory "/var/www/html/app2/current/web">
AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you open use `session_start()`, you will generate a unique session_id to the client if they do not have any session_id before. The session_id is  store in the client cookie. By default, PHP stores the session data in the file.

Each cookie value has different scope. Some cookie value can share across subdomain, some cookies only work on specified directory.

I suspected that you set your session scope to work across subdomain so app2.domain and app1.domain session are shared.

You can [change the scope of your session here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Comment: What about the fact that using different browsers results in the same behavior. That is if I open app1 with chrome then open app2 with Firefox I see app1 on both browsers.

Comment: In this case I'm not sure what code to provide. As I said I'm using the symfony2 framework and it handles the sessions. The issue is either with the way php is sharing sessions or the Apache configuration. I will try out a little test by making a couple of dummy virtual hosts to see how the content gets served. Thanks

Comment: based on further thought and analysis I'm pretty certain that both applications are somehow sharing the same cache. Perhaps not the same filesystem cache but the same memory cache.